# sql syntax problem

Tags: sql, mysql

is there something wrong with this syntax?

```
 SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE uName LIKE '%%' AND tMonth = '3' ORDER BY uName ASC
```

i got this error.. Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..

EDIT

include 'settings.php';

```
$con = connectDB();
$mo = array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
for($mm=1;$mm<13;$mm++) {
    if(strtolower($mo[$mm-1])==strtolower(trim($_GET['uMonth']))) {
        $xyz = $mm;
        break;
    } else {
        $xyz = date("n");
    }
}
$q = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE uName LIKE '%" . $_GET['uName'] . "%' AND tMonth = '" . $xyz . "' ORDER BY uName ASC";
//echo $q;
//exit;
$r = mysql_query($q,$con);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
   echo $row['uName'];
 }
```

Comment: Could the query be failing for some reason? Bad connection, missing table, etc. That could cause mysql_query to return FALSE instead of a handle to the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the sql, it's with the way you call `mysql_fetch_array()`. Try posting your php code too.

Comment: @vrynxzent You should not pass your connection variable `$r` to the `mysql_query` call, according to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your call to `mysql_fetch_array()`, not your query.